# C# equivalent to java prepared statement

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a prepared statement in c#.

For some reason everything I try ends up with an exeption.

This is my code for now:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into daily_cdr_logs " +
            "(message) " +
            "values " +
            "(:message)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(:message, msg);
    //OracleDbType.Int32, postpaid_duration, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I am getting exeption: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Comment: Without sharing the exception details, we can't help much.

Comment: "an exeption" - what one(s)? Can you give the type and message of these exceptions?

Comment: What exception is shown? Also maybe stupid question, but did you open your connection (conn.Open()) before using it?

Comment: Please, add exeption details to your question

Comment: Try to move the Prepare call before the Parameters.Add call and Open connection.

Comment: You should indeed be using a colon (`:` rather than an `@` for Oracle)

Comment: the exception is in Hebrew, but it says, unhandle exeption in the ExecuteNonQuery line. conn is open, moving prepare doest help

Comment: tryed cmd.Parameters.Add(":message", msg); doesnt work still

Comment: where do you open / close your connection?

Comment: And would you mind adding that exception? even if it *is* in hebrew, google should help us get something out of it

Comment: with ":" i get - System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 2):

A typical Oracle prepared statement looks like this.

(notice that only the definition in the prepared statement has the `:` colon, and the one in the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` call does not)

```
String msg = "something here";

using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(...insert connection params here...))
{
  con.Open();
  OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = @"
        insert into daily_cdr_logs
        (message) 
        values 
        (:message)";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("message", msg);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: i already have an open connection and it cant find AddWithValue

Comment: The parameter name supplied to `AddWithValue(string, object)` may have be prepended with a colon and may be not. It is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
//create a connection
string conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString);

//create SQL and insert parameters
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into daily_cdr_logs (message) values (:_message)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("_message", msg));

    try
    {
        //if connection is closed, open it
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
             con.Open();

             //execute query
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //do something with the error
    }
    finally
    {
         //if connection is open, close it
         if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
         con.Close();
    }
```

I have created my connection string in my web.config file, demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431147/how-to-write-connection-string-in-web-config-file-and-read-from-it).

Answer (score 0):

First—your code will not compile, because `:message` is not a valid
*C#* identifier. The line adding the parameter should be:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(":message", msg);
```

Second—it is more efficient to *register* parameters at the prepare
stage:

```
par = cmd.CreateParameter();
par.ParameterName = ":message";
cmd.Parameters.Add( par );
```

and supply the value in each invocation of the prepared query:

```
cmd.Parameters[i].Value = message;
```

if you keep track of your parameters, and

```
cmd.Parameters[":message"].Value = message;
```

if you don't.

Third—the `Prepare()` method in *ODP.NET* does
[nothing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleCommandClass.htm#ODPNT596).
It is there only to satisfy the *IDbCommand* interface, that requres a
[`Prepare()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand.prepare)
method. It is rather deplorable that although *Oracle* have
[implemented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
the prepare functionality for the native *JDBC* interface, they decided
not against it for *ADO.NET*. On the other hand, *ODP.NET* is advertised
to
[cache](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/2015/optimizing_data_access_performance_with_odpnet/optimizing%20data%20access%20performance%20with%20odpnet.html#section1)
repeating queries locally, which should help a bit.

As to the exception you are getting, I think it has nothing to do with
`.Prepare()`. Try the same code without it and see if the exception
remains. The most probable cause is that your connection is not open,
so that it will not work regardless of `.Prepare()`.