# c# oracle sql prepared statement

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am trying to create a prepared statement in c#.

For some reason everything I try ends up with an exeption.

*. This is my code for now:

the exception i am getting is: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into daily_cdr_logs " +
                "(message) " +
                "values " +
                "(:message)";

        cmd.Parameters.Add(:message, msg);
        //OracleDbType.Int32, postpaid_duration, ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

- i have seen some people doing this with Parameters.AddWithValue. but for some reason i cant find the function AddWithValue in OracleCommand.Parameters, i have imported Oracle.DataAccess.Client and i have oracle DataAccess refferance, using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Did you open the connection before?

Comment: Don't you asked it before ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921492/c-sharp-equivalent-to-java-prepared-statement

Comment: The exception is raised by the Prepare line or by the ExecuteNonQuery line?

Comment: try `cmd.Parameters.Add("message", DbType.Varchar).value = msg;`

Comment: Fist—your code will not compile, because `:message` is not a valid
*C#* identifier. The line adding the parameter should be: `cmd.Parameters.Add(":message", msg);`
Second—it is more efficient to *register* at prepare stage
and supply the values in each invocation of the prepared query.

Comment: The `Prepare()` method in *ODP.NET* does
[nothing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleCommandClass.htm#ODPNT596).
It is there only to satisfy the *IDbCommand* interface, that requres a
[`Prepare()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand.prepare)
method.

Comment: It is rather deplorable that although *Oracle* have
[implemented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
the prepare functionality for the native *JDBC* interface, they decided
not against it for *ADO.NET*. On the other hand, *ODP.NET* is advertised
to
[cache](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/2015/optimizing_data_access_performance_with_odpnet/optimizing%20data%20access%20performance%20with%20odpnet.html#section1)
repeating queries locally, which should help.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is open a connection only when necessary and close / dispose it as soon as you're done. The connection pool is managed automatically, so opening a new connection is not reall a heavy task. When you open a connection, close it and open the same connection again, a new native connection isn't really created. The previous one is fetched from the connection pool. The defaults are usually fine so I'd recommend not passing pooling stuff when creating the connection. If you're executing 10 commands in succession, open a connection, execute 10 commands and close it. Do that only if they are guranteed to be executed one after the other and you're not "holding on" to connections when doing other things. If you need to do something else, close the connection before doing so. This usually results in best performance.

Almost. Try:

```
cmd = new command(...);
cmd.parameters.Add(...)
cmd.parameters.Add(...)
```

then `connection.open()`
//execute command and use results

Answer (score 0):

The connection needs to be open before you call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Try this:

```
cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into daily_cdr_logs " +
                "(message) " +
                "values " +
                "(:message)";

         OracleParameter pMsg = new OracleParameter("message",OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            pMsg.Value = msg;

         cmd.Parameters.Add(pMsg);

        //OracleDbType.Int32, postpaid_duration, ParameterDirection.Input);
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: DbType.Varchar; does not exists , maybe oracledbtypes?

Comment: @susparsy Maybe `Varchar2` ? I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Sql Server version of the Prepare command requires

> Before you call Prepare, specify the data type of each parameter in
>   the statement to be prepared. For each parameter that has a variable
>   length data type, you must set the Size property to the maximum size
>   needed. Prepare returns an error if these conditions are not met

Because the Prepare command is defined in the IDbCommand class and inherited by other ADO.NET classes I suppose that this is true also for Oracle, thus add the following lines to add the parameter to your command (and be sure the connection is already open when you call Prepare)

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into daily_cdr_logs (message) " +
                  "values (:message)";
OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter(":message", DbType.Varchar);
p.Size = 2000; // as a wild guess
p.Value = msg;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```