# when i re-run the application i can't find the Data at the Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I added the Data at the Database I can not find it on, but its shows to me, it is added, but when I re-run the application I can not find
this is my sqlconnection :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|direct.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

and i use app config because i wanna deploye my application on machine client

```
 <add name="DIRECTPERFERMANCE.Properties.Settings.directConnectionString"
connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\direct.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29558863/4513879

Comment: Show us you code which actually writes to database.

Comment: Did you include your MDF file between your project files? If yes what is the value of the property `Copy to Output Directory`?

Comment: WHEN EDIT MYSQL CONNECTION LIKE that :

Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\direct.mdf;Database=direct;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
ITS WORK BUT WHEN I DEPLOY THE APPLIC 
ITS SHOWS ME THERE ARE OTHER DATABASE WITH THE SAME NAME

Answer (score 0):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Direct`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Direct;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: i try to add data but it shows me error echec d'instance.
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Direct;Integrated Security=True