# C# Login page. SQL Database path

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

Recently I found a video and managed to code a simple login page with a SQL server involved as I need to hand up this project to my teacher.

I would like to ask is there any way to edit my program so that the database is connected to my program despite whatever computer it is on?

Let me eleborate this is my current code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Glenntdy\Desktop\GlennTeo_Project\GlennTeoProject\GlennTeoDB\GlennTeoDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From GlennTeoDB where Username='"+txtName.Text + "' and Password = '" +txtPassword.Text + "'",con);


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {

        this.Hide();

        Main ss = new Main();
        ss.Show();

        txtName.Text = "";
        txtPassword.Text = ""; 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please double check your Username and password");
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = ""; 
        }
```

The program works fine!

But according to the code, if I were to run it in another computer without editing the code,specifically the "@"Data source" it will not run.

As the path "C:\Users\Glenntdy" will most probably not exist. Is there anyway to fix this issue?

This is a link to a screenshot of my code in case the text is not clear enough.
[http://i.imgur.com/xzWrkIm.png](https://i.imgur.com/xzWrkIm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the .MDF file is with in the project solution. Move the file to `\bin\debug` folder and use below code for connection string

```
 string dbPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf";
```

and use this path for the sql connection...

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I have moved my database to \bin\debug but which line do i replace with " string dbPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf"; " ?

Comment: @MrTeo `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source(LocalDB)\v11.0;
AttachDbFilename="+Application.StartupPath + "\GlennTeoDB.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But when I copy what you wrote I got an "Unrecognized escape sequence" error. I fixed it by changing "\GlennTeoDB.mdf" to "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf" and got even more error.

Comment: The error I got by using "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf" is " {"Keyword not supported: 'data source(localdb)\\v11.0; attachdbfilename'."} "

Comment: @MrTeo Sorry my issue `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename="+Application.StartupPath + "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");` try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77492/discussion-between-sachu-and-mrteo).

Comment: Ah, Thanks Sachu! I have already done so. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

While Sachu answer is exactly correct for this question. I can add little bit more suggestion. You are working on desktop application so when you deploy this application as setup, please add that database in application folder.

Now modify you first line on code such as

```
String connnectionString = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\v11.0;
      AttachDbFilename="+Application.StartupPath+"\SampleDatabase.mdf;
      Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
```

For your development environment if you copy the DB in dubug folder this code will run smoothly.

Comment: Hello, I have copied what you have written and edit the "sampledatabase.mdf" to my database name but I will have an error. "{"The user instance login flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server. The connection will be closed."}"

Comment: Just remove "User Instance=True"

Comment: Thanks Nazmul, your answer is similar to Sachu's. Both are correct and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can give a connection string in web config file

[Declaring connection in only one form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558863/4513879)

When you want to change the  connection string then only change in the web config file.