# key word not supported "data source" ,what's the error i it?

Tags: c#, connection-string

```
label1.Text=textBox1.Text;
string providerName = "System.Data.EntityClient";
string connection = "datasource=students.mssql.somee.com;port=4096;username=someusername;password=somepassword";
SqlConnection Conn=new SqlConnection(connection);
SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter=new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommandBuilder cb=new SqlCommandBuilder(DataAdapter);
Conn.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
Conn.Close();
```

Comment: You may have posted your password.  you should change that immediately.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29558863/4513879

Comment: Besides everything else, you should also reference the `SqlClient` - not the `EntityClient` - in your provider name: `string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";`

Answer (score 3):

In your connection string datasource is a single word seperate with a space as below and try.

```
string connection = 
    "data source=students.mssql.somee.com;
    port=4096;username=*******;password=*******"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string

Remember to try catch

```
label1.Text=textBox1.Text;
string providerName = "System.Data.EntityClient";
string connection = "datasource=students.mssql.somee.com;port=4096;username=mhs_SQLLogin_1;password=gtwhp7td39";
try{
SqlConnection Conn=new SqlConnection(connection);
SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter=new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommandBuilder cb=new SqlCommandBuilder(DataAdapter);
Conn.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
Conn.Close();
}catch(Exception ex){
}
```