# Need Help in connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, connection

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="mycollegeproject" connectionString="Data Source=mssql2.gear.host;Initial Catalog=mycollegeproject;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mycollegeproject;Password=*******" />
</connectionStrings>

public static string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycollegeproject"].ConnectionString;
```

And the error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Show us the web.config please

Comment: Do you have connection string "mycollegeproject" in `app.config`/`web.config`? Name of connection string is case sensitive

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Don't mention password in the post.

Comment: Refer this link
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431147/how-to-write-connection-string-in-web-config-file-and-read-from-it

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If not wrong, mostly you have no connection string defined in your `App.config` named `mycollegeproject` (OR) you are using a different key name in your code rather than using `mycollegeproject` and so the below code line returns `NULL` resulting in NRE.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycollegeproject"]
```