# how to change sql statement to parameterized query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have an sql query that I need change to parameters so I can avoid sql injection.

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT c.*,(Select Initials FROM users WHERE User_ID = c.CreatedByUser) AS CreatedBy, (SELECT Initials FROM users WHERE User_ID = c.ModifiedByUser) AS ModifiedBy FROM currency c WHERE c.Company_ID = " + Company_ID + " AND c.CurrencyCode = '" + Code.Replace("'", "''") + "' ORDER BY c.Description
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("company_ID", Company_ID));
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("code", Code));
```

I know for Company_ID I need to change it to `WHERE c.Company_ID = ?company_ID` but I am not sure what to do for `c.CurrencyCode = '" + Code.Replace("'", "''") + "'`

I just don't know how to change the `Code.Replace` part, since its not a simple as company_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer. `c.CurrencyCode = '" + Code.Replace("'", "''") + "'` simply changes to `c.CurrencyCode = ?code`

Answer (score 2):

As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921492/c-sharp-equivalent-to-java-prepared-statement)

Try using (for odbc for example):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?CURRENCY", OdbcType.VarChar, Code.Replace("'", "''"))
```

Odbc approach

```
OdbcCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM userdetails WHERE USER_ID IN (?, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID1", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID2", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email2;
```

For oracle:

```
//create SQL and insert parameters
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into daily_cdr_logs (message) values (:_message)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("_message", msg));
```

For mysql:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_username=@val1 AND admin_password=PASSWORD(@val2)", MySqlConn.conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", tboxUserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", tboxPassword.Text);
cmd.Prepare();
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include all the code I have. My only problem is how to change Code.replace in the statement

Answer (score 1):

So a parameterized query (to me at least) generally means that you have created a stored procedure on your database and then use your code to execute the stored procedure while passing in the relevant parameters.

This has a couple of benefits

1. DRY - you don't have to repeat the query in code, you can just call the execute method and pass in the appropriate parameters
2. Helps prevent SQL injection - You can only modify the parameters which hopefully will be sanitized before being passed to the query

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) is how to create a stored procedure according to MSDN

and

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx) is how to execute a a stored procedure according to MSDN

If you are determined to do it via LINQ, MSDN has what you are looking for [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

**EDIT**: It seems you are concerned about sql-injection (which is good!), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) is an article (again from MSDN) that covers that topic pretty extensively

Comment: Using parameters with SQL is not limited to stored procedures.

Comment: Very true, I actually specifically noted that *to me* a parameterized query was defined as using a sproc in a database, however the last link in the post shows some other methods of using things like LINQ to make parameterized queries